# Confusions about 虽然 and 即使

Tags: word-choice, usage, word

I'm a Chinese native, but even though I can't figure out the differences between `虽然` and `即使` clearly.
Here're definitions of these two words in *现代汉语词典 (Modern Chinese Dictionary)* (Edition VI).

> **【虽然】suīrán**
> *连词.* 用在上半句，下半句往往有“可是、但是”与它呼应，表示承认甲事为事实，但乙事不因为甲事而成立。
> *Conj.* Used in the first half of the sentence, the second half of the sentence often has "but" to correspond it, expressing the recognition that matter A is a fact, but matter B is not established by matter A.

> **【即使】jíshǐ**
> *连词.* 表示假设的让步。`注意`“即使”所表示的条件，可以是**尚未实现**的事情，也可以是与既成**事实相反**的事情。
> *Conj.* Represents a concession of assumptions. `Note` The condition of "即使" can be something that has **not yet been realized**, or it can be the **opposite of a fact**.

However, I was writing a composition for school and came across the following expression:

> 作为学生，我们*每日坐在教室里学习*，但**即使**这样，“劳动”离我们也并不遥远。
> As students, we *study in the classrooms every day*. (but) **Even though**, "labour" isn't far from us.

I am suspecious about whether I used `即使` correctly. *每日坐在教室里学习 (study in the classrooms every day)* is a fact, so according to dictionary definition, I ought to use `虽然`, but `即使` is widely spoken and I feel it's right, judging from the *feeling for language* (*语感*, I'm not sure if I got the right translation). So what exactly should I use in this sentence?

Comment: 虽然 is for the indicative mood. 即使 is for the subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 作为学生，我们每日坐在教室里学习，但即使这样，“劳动”离我们也并不遥远。

Colloquially, your sentence is ok.  However it's not a good writing.  即使 is usually used when the condition is opposite to the fact.  E. g.  即使他在，我也会这么说。(it implies ***he is actually not here***) If he is truly there, we would say: 虽然他在场，但我还是这么说了。

So your sentence can be improved like this:

> 作为学生，虽然我们每日坐在教室里学习，但“劳动”离我们并不遥远。

Compare this two sentences:

> 即使我付出了真心，他也不在乎。// imply I didn't 付出了真心.

> 虽然我付出了真心，但他也不在乎。// imply I did 付出了真心.

Hope this could help.

Answer (score 1):

> 【即使】jíshǐ ..... 也可以是与既成事实相反的事情。

1. 即使 (despite)
2. action: 每日坐
3. *(仍) still*
4. result: 离劳动不遥远

We expect the result of **sit every day** to be **far away from labor**

Despite the action '每日坐',  which should yield the result of 离劳动遥远, we got the opposite result of '离劳动不遥远'

[即使] 我们每日坐在教室里 (仍) 离劳动不遥远 = [虽然] 我们每日坐在教室里 (卻) 离劳动不遥远